# How do I make two unordered list fade in and fade out when my menu is clicked depending on which is showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu made with 3 div's nested in one div, that I am trying to have two different unordered list fade in or fade out depending on which one is showing when it is clicked. It almost works, however after i click on the menu the first time, every other time both list fade in together instead of just one.

HTML and CSS are good, but in js I've tried several variations of code to get it working, but this is the closest I can get it to work.

```js
   $(document).on('click','.menu', function()
{ 
    $(".pagelinks").fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(".homelinks").fadeIn('slow');
    });

});


$(document).on('click','.menu', function()
{ 
    $(".homelinks").fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(".pagelinks").fadeIn('slow');

    });
});
```

```css
html,body
{
    margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;

}

body
{
    background: url(best8.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 85px;
    position: fixed;
}

h1
{
    
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 3em ;
    top: 100px;
    left: 595px;
}


.logo img
{
    left: 0;
    filter: brightness 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu 
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 77%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 11px;
}

.nav div
{
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav
{
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0 0 
}

.one
{
    width: 30px;
}

.two
{
    width: 20px;
}

.three
{
    width: 25px;
}

.nav:hover div 
{
    width: 30px; 
}

.nav:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pagelinks
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 37%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    display: none;
    
    
    
}

.pagelinks ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.pagelinks ul li 
{
    float: left;
    padding:30px;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 40px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    
}

.pagelinks ul li:hover
{
    color: green;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.logo img:hover
{
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.homelinks
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 54%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    display: block; 
}

.homelinks ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.homelinks ul li 
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:30px;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 40px;
    
}

.homelinks ul li:hover
{
    color: deepskyblue;
    transition: 0.6s;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Goesta Calculators</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" async></script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/axs3axn.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true});}catch(e){}</script>
    
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
    
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <a href="" class="logo"> <img src="NewLogo.PNG" ></a>
           <div class="menu">
           <div class="nav">
               <div class="one"></div>
                <div class="two"></div>
                <div class="three"></div>  
            </div>
           </div>
           <nav class="pagelinks">
               <ul>
                   <a href="" class="home"><li>Mortgage</li></a>
                   <a href="" class="about"><li>Auto</li></a>
                   <a href="" class="personal"><li>Personal</li></a>
                   <a href="" class="refinance"><li>Refinance</li></a>
                   <a href="" class="investment"><li>Investment</li></a>
               </ul>
           </nav>
          </div>
          <nav class="homelinks">
              <ul>
                  <a href="" class="home"><li>Home</li></a>
                  <a href="" class="about"><li>About</li></a>
                  <a href="" class="contact"><li>Contact</li></a>
              </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </header>
     <div>
      <h1>Estimate. Plan your future.</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the asynchronous nature of Javascript. What's happening is when you click the '.menu' for the first time two callback functions are called which get stacked in the event loop and when they execute '.homelinks' and '.pagelinks' both fade in.
What you need to do is simply give a class named **'visible'** to any one of the two ('.homelinks' or '.pagelinks') and in your function just check for the element with **visible** class - fade this element out and fade the other one in and after that toggle **visible** class to the other element and remove **visible** class from original element.

```
For instance
initially - '.homelinks' has visible
            '.pagelinks' does not have it

Now on click event
fadeout - element with visible class ('.homelinks')
fadein  - the other element ('.pagelinks')
remove  - visible class from '.homelinks'
add     - visible class to '.pagelinks'
```

Here check [this](https://codepen.io/manish-baghel/pen/yrQVzy) out in Codepen

```
$('.menu').click(function()
{ 
  console.log("clickk");
    let pl  = $('.pagelinks');
    let hl  = $('.homelinks');
    if(pl.hasClass('visible')){
      pl.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        hl.toggleClass('visible');
        pl.toggleClass('visible');
        hl.fadeIn('slow',function(){});
      });
    }else{
      hl.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        hl.toggleClass('visible');
        pl.toggleClass('visible');
        pl.fadeIn('slow',function(){});
      });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a situation in which you could use the `toggleClass()` function. Create and apply a `.visible` class on one of the `<nav>` elements. On the click event, do something like `$('nav').toggleClass('visible')`. See https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/.